# Oracle CRM On-Demand - Online Technical Resources for Customization

Tags: oracle, crm, ondemand

Does anyone have a good site or online resource for customizing the Oracle CRM On-Demand application?  I have the Help File and Web Service documentation, but there doesn't seem to be much value in the existing forums or sparsely available articles/pod casts.

I'm a new administrator for our company's instance and there doesn't seem to be a lot out there for examples or success stories.

Any resources are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code for integration with CRM OnDemand from C#, VB and Java can be found on [Oracle code samples site](https://codesamples.samplecode.oracle.com/servlets/Scarab/action/ExecuteQuery?query=crm_on_demand), although you'll need to register (for free) to access them.

It's possible to find information on Integration development (i.e. using Web Services), Application customization tips etc. on the [official Oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=162).

You can also find some useful info on these blogs (sorry for these not being hyperlinks - I don't have enough reputation yet):

- crmondemandtricks.com/
- crmondemandpodcast.com/
- blogs.oracle.com/crmodtraining/

But as always, the trial and error way is the most effective. I prefer soapUI (soapui.org) to play with our CRMOD Staging environment.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I think I'll get a lot of use out of the soapUI tool!